# Trouble Login to Heroku on MAC OS X, Yosemitie

Tags: heroku, osx-yosemite

I have installed Heroku Toolbelt on my MAC OS X Yosemite, using the command `brew install heroku`. I have also installed PostgreSQL.

However, when I try `heroku login`, I get the following error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/openssl.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/openssl.bundle
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl.rb:17:in `'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/heroku-toolbelt/3.42.22/libexec/vendor/gems/excon-0.45.4/lib/excon.rb:6:in `'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/heroku-toolbelt/3.42.22/libexec/lib/heroku/jsplugin.rb:127:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/heroku-toolbelt/3.42.22/libexec/lib/heroku/cli.rb:24:in `start'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/heroku-toolbelt/3.42.22/libexec/bin/heroku:24:in `'
```

If I type: "ls -alh /usr/lib/libssl*" on my machine, I get:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    44B Jan 20 11:58 /usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib -> /Users/layla/anaconda/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    18B Apr 14  2015 /usr/lib/libssl.dylib -> libssl.0.9.8.dylib
```

I would appreciate if anybody can help me solve this issue.

Comment: Apologies, I can't give you a full answer but this might have something to do with the fact that Apple no longer ships OpenSSL with OS X and instead bundles it's own TLS and crypto libraries. A `brew install openssl` might resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Chris but openssl-1.0.2e is already installed on my machine.